# IntelliJ IDEA 13 - missing Android UI designer?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've recently installed IntelliJ IDEA 13 and I'm looking for Android UI designer - which always appeared after opening layout xml file - and I could switch between viewing/editing XML and using Designer by there two tabs at the bottom:

[image: Design / Text tabs]

But now, with IntelliJ IDEA 13 these tabs are missing, and file is always opened as XML, without possibility to switch to Design mode. Layout file is properly detected by IDE - it's possible to open "Preview" and to display that layout. Just WYSIWYG editor is missing. It has been removed from new IntelliJ version or is it just me who can't find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have the **Android Designer** plugin installed and enabled in Intellij Settings (ctr+alt+S) -> Plugins. It's a different plugin then Android Support.

Comment: I have this plugin installed, I even disabled and re-enabled it and it never appears.... I'm on Windows 8.1 if that makes a difference, using IntelliJ community edition 13.1.... any one else have this problem?