# IntelliJ IDEA 14 where can I get Android Designer?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, intellij-idea

This question is related to [IntelliJ IDEA 13 - missing Android UI designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856668/intellij-idea-13-missing-android-ui-designer)

I have IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 and the same problem as mentioned in above question, but I am not able to find Android Designer. What have been changed in new IntelliJ?

Comment: Android Designer is no longer a separate plugin; it's been merged into the main Android plugin. Do you have the Android facet configured in your project?

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution. Please post your answer so I can accept it. Otherwise I will close it as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Designer is no longer a separate plugin; it's been merged into the main Android plugin. The UI designer functionality is available for projects that have an Android facet configured.

Answer (score 0):

Grab `Android Studio` - it's IntelliJ IDEA with Android support, officially supported by Google.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I am using `IntelliJ IDEA` for Java development and I've read that it actually has the same features as `Android Studio`

Comment: I think it's the other way around - `Android Studio` have the same features as `IntelliJ IDEA` *plus* Android goodies from Google. You can use IDEA for Android development for sure, but it's a second-class solution compared to officially blessed `Android Studio`.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA regularly merges all Android-related changes from Android Studio, so no, it's not a second-class solution by any means.

Comment: AS is first. IDEA follows the leader, so it cannot be first. It's quite obvious who's the boss in this setup - Google's AS.